# overflowing RenderFlex flutter

Tags: button, checkbox, icons, row, flutter-layout

I am trying to make a seemingly easy page with flutter.

It contains of totally five rows where row 1 & 2, 3 & 4 belongs together, and the last row is its own.

Row 1: Centered text
Row 2: 8 icon buttons

Row 3: Centered text
Row 4: 5 checkboxes

Row 5: Text with a following icon button

The problem I get is the size:
I/flutter (22610):◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢
A RenderFlex overflowed by 248 pixels on the right.

I have tried to make the code in different classes, according to their belonging, but then I get this error.
When I tried to put the code in containers, the iconButtons and checkBoxes quit working. I have read a lot of questions about similar problems here on Stackoverflow and googled around about it, but I'm still stuck.

```
class MyIcon extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyIconState createState() => _MyIconState();
}

class _MyIconState extends State<MyIcon> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      //   body: Container(
      //     height: 180.0,
      //   color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,

  body: Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          ),
          Text(
            'FIRST TEXT',
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25.0,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

        children: <Widget>[

     //         Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 3.0, right: 10.0)),
              _IconButtons(
                headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          _IconButtons(
            headImageAssetPath: 'assets/ico.png',
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            "SECOND TEXT'",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      MyCheckBox(),
    ],
  ),
  //     ),
);
  }
}

class _IconButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  final iconSize = 60.0;
  final String headImageAssetPath;
  final onPressed;

  _IconButtons({this.headImageAssetPath, this.onPressed});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        iconSize: iconSize,
        icon: Image.asset(headImageAssetPath),
        onPressed: () {});
  }
}

class MyCheckBox extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyCheckBoxState createState() => _MyCheckBoxState();
}

class _MyCheckBoxState extends State<MyCheckBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "ANOTHER TEXT",
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is one of many tries. If you want I can send the code for the checkboxes too. (I'm new to flutter so I'm sorry if my code is bad).

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `row 2`, every button icon width valued `60`, then the `Row` container will width valued `60 * 8 = 480` at least, so the error occurs.

I have two solutions for you:

1. If you want to keep the button size width valued `60`, you can replace `Row` with `Wrap`, the button will start a new row when it meet the edge of the screen.
2. If you want the 8 buttons placed in `one single row`, you can wrap the `IconButton` with `Expanded`

```dart
    return Expanded(child:IconButton(
      iconSize: iconSize,
      icon: Image.asset(headImageAssetPath),
      onPressed: () {}
    ));
```